# Upgrade from EF 4 to 6, class inheritence and Discriminator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a EF 4 solution that I'm trying to move to a newer EF (and .net)
I've upgraded EF and fixed all the projects so handle EF 6 and new target platform. 
The problem is that EF4 and 6 handles class inheritance in db in different ways. I have a class BackendUser that inherit the User class. In db the BackendUser table will have BackendUser properties AND a UserId that will get User properties

When upgrading the EF tries to get all data from User table and have the Discriminator property to handle class.

I'm guessing I will have to either convert db to the new way or set EF to handle inheritance the "old" way. I'm also guessing that the new way may be better with performance?

Is there any Best Practice how to handle this to get the old solution to the new db structure or am I looking at hours of manually updating the db?

Edit: found more information about TPT and added classes, so I'm guessing EF don't handle the table attribute for some reason? (some props are left out)

```
[Table("ResellerContact")]
public class ResellerContact : BackendUser
{        
    public string ResellerName {get; set; }
}

[Table("BackendUser")]
public class BackendUser : User
{
    public bool IsSystemOwner { get; set;}     
}

public abstract class User 
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessageResourceName = "UsernameValidationMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    [Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(ResellerContactResource))]
    public string UserName { get; set;}
}
```

Get a backend user results in the following sql

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
[Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
[Extent1].[IsSystemOwner] AS [IsSystemOwner], 
[Extent1].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
[Extent1].[Phone1] AS [Phone1], 
[Extent1].[Mobile1] AS [Mobile1], 
[Extent1].[ResellerContactType] AS [ResellerContactType], 
[Extent1].[Language1] AS [Language1], 
[Extent1].[ResellerId] AS [ResellerId], 
[Extent1].[IsActive1] AS [IsActive1]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'ResellerContact',N'BackendUser')) AND ([Extent1].[UserName] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Password] = @p__linq__1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some tests and this should work, using the `Table` attribute

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<BackendUser> BackendUsers { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ResellerContact> ResellerContacts { get; set; }
}
```

This is the migration code generated, which is TPT and should match your database:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Users",
    c => new
        {
            UserId = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
            UserName = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.BackendUser",
    c => new
        {
            UserId = c.Long(nullable: false),
            IsSystemOwner = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId)
    .Index(t => t.UserId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.ResellerContact",
    c => new
        {
            UserId = c.Long(nullable: false),
            ResellerName = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.BackendUser", t => t.UserId)
    .Index(t => t.UserId);
```

Comment: TPC would create all the db fileds in all tables. The db is generated using EF4 and I have all syntax the same now. The original is TPT where BackendUser have a UserId and all User data is stored in User Table. The EF6 tries to do TPH even with attribute

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry, understood the question wrong. If you want `TPT`, the `Table` attribute should work, but you'd need a single `DbSet<User>` in your `DbContext`

Comment: I have a generic repository for some of the classes and BackendUser is one of these. What I do when error raise is Context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault<T>(t => t.username = username). It worked pre upgrade but now it will use discriminator instread.

Comment: @Trixz see my edit, this -should- work, please test it and let me know how it went

Comment: I actually made a simple test, and it works with the `Table` attribute too (I've re-edited). Just add a set of `User`, along the two inherited ones

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem and it was the Entity Framework version.

I've updated the Entity Framework, resolved some reference issues regarding System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (with others) and then changed the taget version to .Net 4.6

I then found links that stated that Entity Framework needed to reinstall for new target and did not remove from all projects. So when I installed it, it kept installing for .Net 4.0

So, uninstall Entity Framework on all projects, add it again so target will get right and [Table] still works. I'm guessing the annotation attribute was from wrong library and not handled by entity framework correctly.

Reference: [Can I implement Entity Framework 5 TPT on Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963417/can-i-implement-entity-framework-5-tpt-on-windows-xp)

TPT is still a performance issue (section 7.2 in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh949853) and I will try to change it to TPH. To resolve this I found that I will create a migration for my current db, and then remodel the classes to get a migration scripts how to update the tables.
This thread pointed me to that direction
[Entity Framework Code First Convert TPT to TPH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244257/entity-framework-code-first-convert-tpt-to-tph)

Thanks @Jcl for input